# How to push new value in array useState in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I want when I click on a card of the movie name, this movie name is pushed in useSate. The problem is when I click on the same card, data is saved in the useState as an array. But when I click on a different card previous value of the useState is deleted.

Here is my code. `movie` is a single object.

```
const MovieCard = ({ movie }) => {
    const [firstCat, setFirstCat] = React.useState([]);
    



    const movieList = (movie) => {
        setFirstCat([...firstCat, movie]);
    }

    console.log(firstCat);

    return (
        <div className='mt-3 cursor-pointer' onClick={() => movieList(movie)}>
            <div className="max-w-sm bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md">

                <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="/docs/images/blog/image-1.jpg" alt="" />

                <div className="p-5">

                    <h5 className="mb-2 text-xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900">{movie.Title}</h5>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MovieCard;
```

when clicking on the same card, useState is like this,
[image: clicking on the same card]

When clicking on the different card
[image]

Comment: Looks like each `MovieCard` component has its own `firstCat` state. When you click another movie card you are updating *that* card's state. Can you share a more [complete and comprehensive code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying to do? You likely need to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and store the `firstCat` state in the common parent component so all `MovieCard` components can reference the same single state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you scoped your states only in `MovieCard` which means each `MovieCard` will have different states.

You need to add states on the upper/parent component of `MovieCard`. Let's assume you have `MovieList` contains all `MovieCard`

```
const MovieList = () => {
   const [firstCat, setFirstCat] = React.useState([]);

   console.log(firstCat);

   return <div>
      <MovieCard movie={movie} setFirstCat={setFirstCat}/>
   <div/>
}
```

And modify your `MovieCard` like below

```
const MovieCard = ({ movie, setFirstCat }) => {

    const movieList = (movie) => {
        setFirstCat([...firstCat, movie]);
    }

    return (
        <div className='mt-3 cursor-pointer' onClick={() => movieList(movie)}>
            <div className="max-w-sm bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md">

                <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="/docs/images/blog/image-1.jpg" alt="" />

                <div className="p-5">

                    <h5 className="mb-2 text-xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900">{movie.Title}</h5>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MovieCard;
```

This technique is called [state lifting](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like each `MovieCard` component has its own `firstCat` state. When you click another movie card you are updating *that* card's state.

You likely need to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and store the `firstCat` state in the common parent component so all `MovieCard` components can reference the same single state.

Example:

```
const Movies = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = React.useState([.......]);
  const [firstCat, setFirstCat] = React.useState([]);

  const addMovie = (movie) => {
    setFirstCat(firstCat => [...firstCat, movie]);
  }

  return movies.map(movie => (
    <MovieCard
      key={movie.id}
      movie={movie}
      addMovie={() => addMovie(movie)}
    />
  ));
}
```

...

```
const MovieCard = ({ movie, addMovie }) => {
  return (
    <div className='....' onClick={addMovie}>
      <div className="....">
        <img
          className="...." 
          src="...."
          alt=""
        />
        <div className="p-5">
          <h5 className="....">
            {movie.Title}
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```